# WCF 4.0 Binding error after deployment

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I create a web service reference from within VS10- from a ASP.NET website too a WCF 4.0 custom service endpoint.  When everything is running/deployed in my sandbox it works fine but when I deploy out to separate servers I get the following error.

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while
>   receiving the
>
> HTTP response to
>   http://mywcfservices.com:888/SvcLibrary.MyService.svc.
>
> This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol.
>
> This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server
>
> (possibly due to the service shutting down).

Here is the **web.config section** generated by VS10 in the ASP.NET client website.  Also I notice it generates a wsHttpBinding binding rather than a HttpBasicBinding is that my problem?  This is not a HTTPS deployment.

```
  <system.serviceModel>

<bindings>

<wsHttpBinding>

<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IXRMService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"

openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"

bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"

maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"

textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">

<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"

maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

<reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"

enabled="false" />

<security mode="Message">

<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"

realm="" />

<message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"

algorithmSuite="Default" />

</security>

</binding>

</wsHttpBinding>

</bindings>

<client>

<endpoint address="http://mywcfservices.com:888/SvcLibrary.MyService.svc"

binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IXRMService"

contract="XRMService.IXRMService" name="WSHttpBinding_IXRMService">

<identity>

<dns value="localhost" />

</identity>

</endpoint>

</client>

</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: check events logs of your server. there should be an activation exception.

Answer (score 0):

wsHttpBindings are not necessarily just for doing HTTPS across web service calls since basicHttp can do that as well, rather the ide defaults to this because wsHttp is going to be a lot more advanced option than basicHttp since it implements the WS-* specifications (particularly around addressing, message-level security, etc).

Can you send your server-side/service-side config xml? This would be the config section that configures the WCF itself (the stuff inside the <service> tag). This would be helpful in seeing why IIS isn't liking your service calls.